# Working with JSON on the Server-Side in ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have an ASP.NET web form that is using JQuery on the client-side. I have a user interface that is building a collection of objects and storing them in JSON. With my client-side implementation complete, I need to now work with that information when the user clicks a button. When this button is clicked, I need to loop through that JSON collection and validate the entries. My problem is, I'm not sure how to do it.

```
// Client-Side Code
var myCollection = {
  "data": [
  ]
};


// Server-Side Code
protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Parse JSON
}
```

Each item in the collection is stored in the "data" property. How do I loop through the JSON collection on the server-side? I thought about putting the JSON data in a Hidden HTML Element, but this didn't sound good and I could think of a good way to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you send it to the server is up to you - a hidden field, an AJAX call, whatever you prefer. Once you've got the string on the server, you'll need 2 things:

1. A C# server-side representation
   of that object
2. A converter to go
   from JSON to that C# representation.

Let's adjust your example a bit, because "myCollection" in your example is an object, not a collection. So we'll call it myObject. Secondly, we'll assume that "data" is an array of strings. It could be anything, but we'll keep it simple.

```
var myObject = {
  data: ["string1","string2"]
};
```

We'll also assume you're using the DataContractJsonSerializer, so you can easily map the two different case-styles...JavaScript is typically camelCase, and C# is typically ProperCase. So, in C#, this would be:

```
[DataContract(Name="myObjectType")]
public class MyObjectType{
  [DataMember(Name="data")]
  public string[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

Now you have two representations of the same structure, one in c#, one in JavaScript. To convert from one to the other, we can use the built-in DataContractJsonSerializer, like this:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
    {
      DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
      return (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
    }
}
```

...resulting in a final call of:

```
MyObjectType myObject = Deserialize<MyObjectType>(incomingString);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON in the Hidden Field is a valid way to do it, as the data would then be posted to the server.  You could then use the System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer component to deserialize the data (to a dictionary) and access the data that way.  Not 100% sure hhow array data comes out of that process.  THere are also other tools like JSON.NET too to parse JSON.

Another way is via a web service call, but that doesn't go through the page lifecycle.

HTH.