# Working with JSON on the Server-Side in ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, javascript, json

This is a follow-up to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367022/working-with-json-on-the-server-side-in-asp-net-and-c). I'm trying to understand how to serialize some JSON. I am using the JSON.stringify() method found in [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json2.js) to convert a JSON array into a string value I can work with on the server-side. My JSON originally looks like this:

```
var myItems = {
    "data": [
      {"id":1, "type":2, "name":"book"},
      {"id":2, "type":3, "name":"dvd"},
      {"id":3, "type":4, "name":"cd"}
    ]
};
```

After I use JSON.stringify, I have noticed that the value on the server looks like the following:

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"type":2,"name":"book"},{"id":2,"type":"3","name":"dvd"},{"id":3,"type":4,"name":"cd"}]}
```

In an effort to serialize this JSON into C# objects I can work with, I have written the following code:

```
public MyItems GetMyItems() 
{
  MyItems items = new MyItems();

  string json = serializedJsonInHiddenHtmlElement.Value;
  if (json.Length > 0)
  {
    items = Deserialize<MyItems>(json);
  }
  return items;
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
  {
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
  }
}
```

The classes associated with my types are defined as follows:

```
[DataContract(Name="myItems")]
internal class MyItems
{
    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public string[] Data { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name="myItem")]
internal class MyItem
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

When I execute this code, the line that says `return (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);` I get an error that says the following:

```
There was an error deserializing the object of type AppNamespace.MyItems. End element 'item' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'id' from namespace ''.
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to get past this. Can somebody please point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What is "Deserialize(" in your code.. from which namespace are you using the deserialize method ?

If this is an asp.net project, if asp.net 3.5+, you should be able to use microsoft ajax extensions which has json deserialization inbuilt.

Answer (score 1):

You could first try to create a MyItems object on the server and serialize it. To see how the output json looks like. I haven't used DataContractJsonSerializer but I think that the wcf attributes make it interpret the json incorrectly.

Also, shouldn't :

```
public string[] Data { get; set; }
```

be

```
public MyItem[] Data { get; set; }
```

?

Comment: I'm interested in going from JSON to C#, not the other way around.

Comment: I understand that, but by looking at the output json from C#, you might see where the problem is with the json sent from the interface. You can see what the C# deserializer is expecting.