# Unable to read JSON object from POST request "ASP.net"

Tags: asp.net, json, c#-4.0, extjs, httprequest

I'm getting a JSON object(i.e. NewDataSet) in the POST request, see image below (Firebug-request object)...

[image]

How can i get this object at server side ??

Thanks
Xtremist

Comment: I think it has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367022/working-with-json-on-the-server-side-in-asp-net-and-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a server side object matching the JSON object you are posting to the server.

```
public class DataPackage
{
    public string CostType {get; set;}
    public string CostName {get; set;}
    public bool isEditable {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

In your webservice you can setup the service definition like this:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]
public void MyWebservice(DataPackage NewDataSet) {
    ...
}
```

You need to tell your client side posting script that you are sending json:

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

If I remember correctly this will tell ASP.NET to deserialize your JSON object into the .NET class.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout information on [JSON.net](http://json.codeplex.com/)